# how to translate multiple rename aggregation variables in sql to python?

Tags: python, sql

There are many aggregated and renamed variables in sql, how can I translate it into python with an efficient way?

**example:**

```
select
      count(distinct id)
      sum(major_violation_3year) as major_violation
      sum(minor_violation_3year) as minor_violation
      sum(suspension_3year) as suspension
      from data1
      group by calendar_month, calendar_year
```

This is what I have tried to write it in python:

**example:**

```
 import numpy as np
 import pandas as pd

 data1.groupby(['calendar_month'],['calender_month']).agg({'major_violation_3year':np.sum,'minor_violation_3year':np.sum,'suspension_3year':np.sum})
```

I don't know if I write it in a correct way, and how to rename all the varialbes. Appreciate if you can provide any idea, thanks!

Comment: Hola! What have you tried so far? Do you have any code you can share which demonstrates what you need but maybe is not quite working etc.

Comment: Hi, I have added some code into the question, it should be easier to understand now.